# Cannot get a single calendar event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble reading a single calendar event, calling:

```
Api::get('me/calendar/'.$id);
```

(API:: is a wrapper for Guzzle)

returns the errors:

> The specified object was not found in the store.

I know it's a valid id as I've listed my calendar events:

```
$records = Api::get("me/calendarview?startdatetime=$start&enddatetime=$end&\$top=1000");

    foreach ($records['value'] as $row) {

        $events[] = array(
            'id' =>  $row['id'],
            'title' => $row['subject'],
            'start' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['start']['dateTime'])),
            'end' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['end']['dateTime'])),
            'allDay' => $row['isAllDay'],
        );

    }

    return $events;
```

The output contains the id:

```
{
"id": "AAMkADdlZTBjNjQ4LWI0OGItNDFhZS05ZDNiLThiY2JkYzIzZWZkYwBGAAAAAABFX7lJCx7ZRLTJ6iI0yZK6BwC8b_tAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAAAAAAEOAAC8b_tAO4nLRZCbkhud5CXFAAMc9p8aAAA=",
"title": "TOP - DC/JB - FEO",
"start": "2017-11-27 15:00:00",
"end": "2017-11-27 16:30:00",
"allDay": false
```

}

I've then used that id and attempted to return a single entry, the same happens when I use the Graph Explorer so I'm wondering if there is a bug or the documentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint for fetching a [single calendar entry](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_get) is `/me/events/{id}`, not `/me/calendar/{id}`:

```
Api::get('me/events/'.$id);
```

The `/calendar` endpoint returns a `Calendar` resource whereas you're looking for an `Event` resource (a child object of the Calendar)

Comment: perfect thank you, you're right I was looking in the wrong place.